# Purge old binlogs in mysql 4

Tags: mysql, binlog

I need to purge binary logs from mysql version 4. I have checked the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-archive.html) found that the syntax is like an advanced versions:

```
PURGE MASTER LOGS TO mysql-bin.xxx
```

However, when i use this command, i get the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (00000): You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BINARY LOGS TO 'mysql-bin.xxx'' at line 1
```

Please avdise.

Comment: 4.0 pre-dates `CHARACTER SET` support, plus lots of other things.  It will be nontrivial to upgrade, which you should do.  If you have `SELECTs` that mix `JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`, add parentheses now; there is an incompatible change coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says `right syntax to use near 'BINARY LOGS TO 'mysql-bin.xxx'` but you mentioned use of `PURGE MASTER LOGS TO ...`?

Try using `PURGE MASTER LOGS TO mysql-bin.xxx` instead of using 'PURGE BINARY ....' as the latter was added to MySQL v4.1.1 and if your version is any lower, `PURGE BINARY ...` won't work.

Comment: I still get the same message. I entered `PURGE MASTER LOGS TO mysql-bin.001` and got: `ERROR 1064 (00000): You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql-bin.001' at line 1`.

Comment: Can you post result of running `SELECT version()`  on MySQL Client?

Comment: 4.0.27-standard-log

Comment: Also, are you using single quotes around the mysql-bin.001? So the command should be like `PURGE MASTER LOGS to 'mysql-bin.xxx'`

Comment: Thanks. The command `PURGE MASTER LOGS` worked with single quotes.